# Wrap DNN page separator in span with aria-hidden="true"?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

The default page separator in DNN is the ">" character.  It looks nice but screen readers read it out as "greater than."  It's not a deal breaker but it sure gets annoying page after page.

Is it possible to wrap that separator in a span with aria-hidden="true"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the breadcrumb control in the skin file. You can change the separator there using any HTML code, but you have to HTML-encode the value. When you look at the "inner.ascx" file of the Xcillion skin, you find

```
Separator="&lt;img src=&quot;/Portals/_default/Skins/Xcillion/Images/breadcrumb-arrow.png&quot; alt=&quot;breadcrumb separator&quot;&gt;"
```

as an example. Therefore, the solution should be

```
<dnn:BREADCRUMB ID="dnnBreadcrumb" runat="server" CssClass="breadcrumbLink" RootLevel="0" Separator="&lt;span aria-hidden=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&nbsp;>&nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" HideWithNoBreadCrumb="true" />
```